# Conditionally Enable Full Text Search using TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have Products table which include Name and ModelNumber. I need to enable Full Text Search on these fields only if the Full Text Search is not enabled before using tsql in SQL Server 2012

Comment: You mean enabling full text search at run time while executing the query? I don't think you can do that.

Comment: @rahul, I just need to do it via TSQL so that I can run TSQL to enable it on production db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but if you are asking TSQL command to enable FULL TEXT search on your table then you can use the below TSQL queries for the same

```
use [DB_NAME]

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG productcat AS DEFAULT;
GO

EXEC [DB_NAME].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
GO
```

(OR)

```
USE [DB_NAME];
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG productcat;
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Products
 ( 
  Name
     Language 1033,
  ModelNumber
     Language 1033   
 ) 
  KEY INDEX PK_Products_ProductName 
      ON productcat; 
GO
```

See [CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) for more information

**EDIT:**

In case you want to know whether FULL TEXT is installed or not; you can use below command

```
select SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

If the above query returns a 1 then the component is installed.

In case you want to check whether a particular table has FULL TEXT enabled

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID('Products'), 'TableHasActiveFulltextIndex');
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I need to allow user to enter model-number or name. Should I use FreeText or Contains

Comment: @user960567, not sure but you will use Contains. You got to check in MSDN once.